# Add smooth transition on header when I scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, sass, css-transitions

I'm trying to add an effect on the header when I scroll down. Basically I want to change the header's color when I scroll. I've made a small javascript code do do that change but I also want to add a smooth transition on that change. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Here's my code and a link to codepen:
https://codepen.io/paulo-frutuoso/pen/wvvREZg

```
<header>
  <nav>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

My sass

```
:root {
  --menuCor: #013220;
  --menuTransparente: rgba(1, 50, 32, 0.2);
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 200vh;
  background: url('https://lisboa.smartmove.pt:8083/Fluminense/DemoPortalTorcedor/images/banner_01.jpg') no-repeat center center; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

header {
      background: var(--menuTransparente);
    position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
      z-index:2;

    nav {
      ul {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
        list-style-type: none;
        height: 60px;

        li {
          a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #fff;
            font-family: 'Open sans';
            font-size: .8rem;
          }  
        } 
      }
    }
  }
```

My JS

```
const htmlTag = document.querySelector('html');
const bodyTag = document.querySelector('body');
const myNav = document.querySelector('header');
const myElem = document.querySelector('header nav li a');

let scrolled = () => {
  let dec = scrollY / (bodyTag.scrollHeight - innerHeight);
  return Math.floor(dec *100);
}

addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  myNav.style.setProperty('background', scrolled() > 20 ? "var(--menuCor)" : "var(--menuTransparente)");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Add to header class this: 
*transition: all .2s ease-in;*

```
header {
  background: var(--menuTransparente);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  z-index:2;
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
```

You can change *all* to *background* to have perfect match with your style.

Comment: Of course. What else? I'm felling stupid. thank you so much ;)

Comment: You are welcome, just click that my answer is correct :D